# Android Canvas.scale() and not rounded numbers

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm scaling some bitmaps in canvas and I have some problems.
I have this image 640x360 and want to fill it to the screen.
My screen is 1196x720px so I have to scale the image by 1.86875 x 2.0 times.

The code is this:

```
canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
canvas.scale((float)(1.86875), (float)(2.0),0,0);
canvas.drawBitmap(this.backgroundMap, 0, 0, null);
canvas.restore();
```

The image is scaling correctly in axis Y but it's wrong of, I think 100 pixels in X axis.
Any idea on how I can resolve this?

thank you =)

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "it's wrong"? Is it distorted, is it in wrong place of the screen?

Comment: It is not 1196x720px in width :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using scale and drawBitmap try using this method:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);
```

You probably should call it this way:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(this.backgroundMap, null, new Rect(0, 0, 1196, 720), null);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. But this is still strange. I'm developing a game in canvas (yes, I know, I should have used opengles but I started the project like a hobby). For the background this way is perfect becouse the image is everytime the same as width and height, but for other assets the dimension change everytime. I was hoping that scale was more reliable :-(